# Multiple docker containers with same container port connected to the same network

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, port, docker-network

I am having an app that depends on multiple docker containers. I use docker compose so that all of them are in the same network for inter-container communication. But, two of my containers are listening to the same port 8080 inside their respective containers but, are mapped to different ports on the host: 8072,8073. For inter-container communication since we use the container's port will this cause problems?

Constraints:

1. I need both the containers for my app to run. Thus I cannot isolate the other container with same internal port to a different network
2. All containers should run on the same host.

Am new to docker and I am not sure how to solve this.

Thanks

Comment: IIUC see the documentation here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/ You need not expose each of the service's ports on the host unless you wish to access them from outside the docker-compose created network. Ports must be unique per host *but* each service in your docker-compose created network can use the same port with impunity and is referenced by <service-name>:<port>. In the Docker example, there could be 2 Postgres services. Each would need a unique name: `db1`; `db2` but both could be have `ports - "5432"` and be uniquely addressable from `web` as `db1:8432` and `db2:8432`.

Comment: So, the containers can have same port in the docker network and can be accessed without issues with the container_name: port?. You mean I can access them as db1: 5432 and db2:5432 ? 5432 and 5433 are container's internal ports

Comment: Yes, each service corresponds effectively to a different host. So, as long as the ports are unique for each service|host, you're good. And, as long as any ports you expose on the host are unique, you're good too.... Extending my example, `db1` could expose port `8432:8432` but then `db2` would need to find a different host port to use, perhaps `8433:8432`.

Comment: I think that would do for a good answer here ;)

Comment: @DazWilkin you should post an answer based on your comments

Answer (score 20, accepted):

IIUC see the documentation here:
https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking

You need not expose each of the service's ports on the host unless you wish to access them from the host, i.e. outside of the docker-compose created network.

Ports must be unique per host *but* each service in your docker-compose created network can use the same port with impunity and is referenced by `<service-name>:<port>`.

In the Docker example, there could be 2 Postgres services. Each would need a unique name: `db1`; `db2` but both could use the same port - "5432" and be uniquely addressable from the service called `web` (and each other) as `db1:8432` and `db2:8432`.

Each service corresponds effectively to a different host. So, as long as the ports are unique for each service|host, you're good. And, as long as any ports you expose on the host are unique, you're good too....

Extending the example, `db1` could expose port `9432:8432` but then `db2` would need to find a different host port to use, perhaps `9433:8432`.

Within the docker-compose created network, you would access `db1` as `db1:8432` and `db2` as `db2:8432`.

From the host (outside the docker-compose create network), you would access `db1` as `localhost:9432` and `db2` as `localhost:9433`.

**NB** It's likely a good practice to only expose service ports to the host when those service's must be accessible from outside (e.g. `web` probably must be exposed but `dbX` probably need not be exposed). You may wish to be more liberal in exposing service ports while debugging.

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by "referenced by :."?

Comment: @barney lost during copy-and-paste from my comment. I've edited the answer to show the value `<service-name>:<port>`