# docker-compose connecting two apps

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-network

I am trying to link two applications with docker compose I have the following yaml file

```
version: '3'
services:
 app1:
   build: 
     context: ../../repos/app1
   ports:
     - "8080:8080"
 app2:
   build: .
   ports:
     - "8081:8080"
```

I know that he ports are arranged as the following  host_port:container_port - https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

This stack overflow is what made me specify the ports so that the containers are on the same container port. [Multiple docker containers with same container port connected to the same network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55192991/multiple-docker-containers-with-same-container-port-connected-to-the-same-networ/55202766)

Then I run a `docker compose up`

I see two images created and two processes running

```
REPOSITORY               TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED      SIZE
main_app2   latest    1d204754b5c3   5 days ago   725MB
main_app1     latest    58e838149b97   5 days ago   754MB
PS C:\Users\am818j\repos\main> docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                                                           NAMES
d6b6c3411670   main_app2   "/opt/jboss/wildfly/…"   8 minutes ago   Up 8 minutes   8443/tcp, 9990/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8081->8080/tcp, :::8081->8080/tcp   main_app2_1
392e8d6da3c7   main_app1     "/opt/jboss/wildfly/…"   8 minutes ago   Up 8 minutes   8443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, :::8080->8080/tcp, 9990/tcp   main_app1_1
```

I can see two processes running and access them from the following urls
http://localhost.test.com:8081/app2/faces/home.faces and http://localhost.test.com:8080/app1/faces/home.faces

But I do not see data flow between app1 and app2. Is it possible to have these two apps communicate with each other? If so what am I missing to be able to test that communication?

Answer (score 1):

You say absolutely nothing about the processes. Are they TRYING to communicate with each other? How? What's the error message?

I am guessing you have them trying to talk to `localhost:8000` and `localhost:8001`. However, each container has its OWN localhost loopback- they don't share one. Instead, they should be talking to `app1:8000` and `app2:8000`. Note `8000` vs `8001` - the `ports` argument maps a port on YOUR interface to a port in THE CONTAINER interface... so far as the container is concerned, it is still listening on port 8000, and your other containers will have to use that.