# How do multiple copies of a Docker image using the same port work normally?

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose

I have a `docker-compose` with 5 containers. See below for an example.

```
services:
 backend:
  image: 'backend:latest'
  ports:
   - "5000:5000"

 service_a:
  container_name: service_a
  image: 'container_a:latest'
  expose:
   - "8089"

 service_b:
  container_name: service_b
  image: 'container_a:latest'
  expose:
   - "8089"

 service_c:
  container_name: service_c
  image: 'container_b:latest'
  expose:
   - "8090"

 service_d:
  container_name: service_d
  image: 'container_b:latest'
  expose:
   - "8090"
```

As you can see, `service_a` and `service_b` exposes the same port, and `service_c` and `service_d` also share the same port. But they are named differently. All four containers have a web API and my backend calls all four containers for calculations.  Surprisingly, even though there are 4 containers sharing 2 ports, the applications still function without issues.  I am wondering why the `docker-compose` works even though there is port collision.

In my application, I do specify the API service as `<container name>:<port>`.  Is the container being named differently the reason why this works even though there is port collision?

Comment: Inside Docker, each container has its own private internal IP address, so there's no port conflicts if multiple containers happen to use the same port.  Compose `expose:` does pretty much nothing and you should remove it if it's present in any of your files.  [Multiple docker containers with same container port connected to the same network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55192991/multiple-docker-containers-with-same-container-port-connected-to-the-same-networ) has some discusion of this.